# Is the use of "this" here incorrect grammatically?

Tags: grammar

My adviser is reviewing my thesis, and he is asking me to minimize using the word "this," and mentioned that my usage is incorrect grammatically. I'm extremely confused how my usage is wrong.

Here is one of the sentences he pointed out:

"A discontinuous galerkin solver was developed as part of **this** thesis."

How is this wrong grammatically?

Comment: It's not incorrect grammatically.

Comment: If you mean _the current thesis_, you should say it directly, instead of relying on the reader to figure out what you were pointing at when you said _this thesis_.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the whole thesis that will be presented for your degree,  it is already clear to the reader that your Galerkin solver is part of the thesis. Why say it again? "*A discontinuous Galerkin solver was developed.*" is sufficient.

I add that it used to be conventional to use the passive voice "*...was developed*" but that you might also use the (preferable) active voice "*I developed a discontinuous Galerkin solver*".

If on the other hand the context is that you have recently introduced a sub-thesis of some sort, "*... of this thesis*" would be acceptable, because *this* refers to what you recently mentioned.

For example: "*One thesis (or proposition?) is that, just as they have been used on the sphere and ellipsoid, DGMs may applied to the shallow water equations on a hyperboloid. A discontinuous Galerkin solver was developed as part of this thesis.*"

Comment: My adviser has steered me away from writing in first person although I see first person usage just in about every other thesis I've read. I think he has some grammatical quirks, which I thought could be because he's Scottish (just saw that you're from Scotland too), but I don't have any knowledge of what the folks in the UK do. Also, I don't think it was clear before that sentence that the solver was developed as part of the thesis because that sentence was essentially part of a quick synopsis.

Comment: Best be prudent and heed your advisor and adopt the passive! It is no longer a Scottish thing - we adhere to national & international conventions, which have been shifting in favour of the active. But there is no point in making a crusade of it. You add that this is part of a synopsis. If the sentence is an early part of a synopsis I think you have good reason to retain the phrase. Why? Because a synopsis is not like my made-up example with its explicit precedent: the precedent (the title?) or sparse introductory context are probably too weak within a synopsis to justify omitting the phrase.